# System of three equation, find alpah for, one solution, no solution and infitne solution

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

Hi guys having and issue with this question. [part a) check and part b) help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdpG5.png)

So for the first part, I just took the inverse matrix which I assume to be correct as, the only two matrixs I know of that give an idenity is A*A^-1.

for the secon part I seemto be getting conflicting results.

So when I look at the bottom two equation they run parallel to each other, so when alpha=6 I should get no solutions, but when I use cramers I see that for the

determinat: D: I get: -a^2+5a+6 setiing that equal to zero I get: a=-1 a=6

for the other determinats

Dx= a^2-7a+6

Dy= -2a+12

Dz=0

now using the condtions for cramers that, if

If D = 0, and at least one of Dx, Dy, or Dz is non-zero, then the system has no solution.

and

If D = 0, and Dx = Dy = Dz = 0, then the system has infinitely many solutions.

I get that if a=6 then I get infintely solutions and when a=-1 I get no solutions.

So as D is only 0 at a=6 and a=1 then for one solution any number beside them two is vaild. Can someone please give advice be much appreciated.

Comment: What di you means by ''when I look at the bottom two equation they run parallel to each other''? $x+\alpha y=1$ and $x-y+3z=-1$ are not parallel planes.

Comment: the lines x-y+3z=-1 and 2x-2y+az=-2. Have I gotten this worng? It just that 2x-2y+az=-2 is a scalar multiple of x-y+3z=-1

Comment: For $a=6$ we have that $2x-2y+az=-2$ is coincident with $x-y+3z=-1$ so we have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Ok thank you I got it the wrong way round. Now that make better sense. Thank you very much for the help it was much appreciated.